# using reinterpret_cast to convert char* to vector<byte>

Tags: c++

I am using a library called botan for encryption. but the case here is not related with the library, it seems to be a issue in c++ or casting. using the library a 16 byte long vector is created as below.

```
  SecureVector<byte> salt = rng.random_vec(16);
```

then it is converted to a string as,

```
  std::string salt_string ((const char*)salt.begin() , salt.size());
```

using Qt i can just read the srting as,

```
  ui->textEdit->append("Salt is : "+ QString::fromStdString(salt_string));
```

now I need to write this to a file and regenerate the vector at a later time.
It is written to a file as,

```
 ofstream outfile ("salt.txt" , std::ios::binary);
 outfile.write((const char*)salt.begin(), salt.size());
```

up to this point the code looks working great and the problem occurs when reading and regenerating the vector.

here is how i read the data to a char* array,

```
  ifstream infile ("salt.txt" , std::ios::binary );
  char* salt = new char[16];
  infile.read(salt , 16 );
```

now I need to recreate the `SecureVector<byte>` as salt2 , I tried to do it using `reinterpret_cast` as below,

```
 SecureVector<byte> salt2 = reinterpret_cast<byte> (salt);
```

which compiles without errors but returns a empty string when try to display as i displayed salt above. what am i doing wrong or how to do the conversion correctly. any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ - pointer array to Vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278347/c-pointer-array-to-vector)

Comment: Which constructor `SecureVector<byte>` has ? I expected one similar to `salt2(salt, salt +16)`

Comment: Do you have any documentation for `SecureVector` I have no idea what that is. So it is impossible to tell what it is expecting for an assignment or constructor.

Comment: @LokiAstari documentation is found here. `http://fossies.org/dox/Botan-1.10.9/classBotan_1_1SecureVector.html` but I have no idea about doing the conversation. thanks in any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your assignment:

```
SecureVector<byte> salt2 = reinterpret_cast<byte>(salt);
```

You are converting the `char*` into a `byte` (So a pointer is being converted to a byte (I assume you meant to convert it to a `byte*` (note the extra `*`) but that did not compile so you took off the `*` to see what would hapen)). What this does is undefined (if not a very bad idea). But You have a byte.

But it compiles because `SecureVector<byte>` has a constructor that takes a `size_t` as a parameter. A `size_t` is an integer as is a byte and thus the compiler generated an auto conversion and constructed you vector using the byte as a size.

What you actually want to do is use the constructor that takes a pointer to byte and a size. see: [SecureVector.](http://fossies.org/dox/Botan-1.10.9/classBotan_1_1SecureVector.html)

```
SecureVector<byte> salt2(reinterpret_cast<byte*>(salt), 16);
```

Comment: You said exactly what i did. Now i got the mistake what i did and got a good idea about what was going on. Why it complied but didnt work... Ect. Thanks again,  this answer helped me a lot

Answer (score 8):

`reinterpret_cast` doesn't magically convert one type to another, even if it appears to do so. Frankly, unless and until you understand what it *does* do, you should *never* use it.

To make a vector contain the bytes from an array, create the vector and then add the bytes to it. You can't do this using a cast.

```
SecureVector<byte> salt2(salt, salt + 16);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it didn't work it now returns an error in compile `C2664: 'Botan::SecureVector<Botan::byte>::SecureVector(const Botan::SecureVector<Botan::byte>`

Comment: I solved the question by adding the line, `SecureVector<byte> salt2((const byte*)salt, 16  )  ;`

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly, but due to the type conversion you may have to just do a for loop here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    salt2.push_back(reinterpret_cast<byte>(salt[i]));
```

I don't think casting like that can work because a vector isn't laid out the same way an array is in memory, it has to contain other information like its size.

Comment: If `byte` is a typedef of `char` or `unsigned char` (or, I think, if `char` is convertible to `byte`) - which seems a reasonable assumption -  then the loop isn't necessary. You can just use the appropriate vector constructor.

Comment: @davmac I was considering adding that, I think you are right that it's a better solution if it works.

Comment: thanks Namfuak, this also didnt work either. this returned an compile time error `C2664: 'Botan::SecureVector<Botan::byte>::SecureVector(const Botan::SecureVector<Botan::byte>`

Comment: @danialweaber `Botan::byte` appears to be a typedef for `uint_8` according to their documentation, so you may need to convert to unsigned char first (or use a C-style cast).