# how to convert from vector<byte> to vector<uint_8> in c++?

Tags: vector, byte, unsigned-integer

In my C++ code , I have to use external library function which has the argument of `vector<uint8_t>.`

But in my source , I keep my variable as vector , so how would I do the conversation from `vector<byte>` to `vector<unint8_t>` while the variable gets passed into the function.

My source is given below.

//external library function from header:

```
uint16_t  GetLinkCRC16(const vector<uint8_t> &buffer);


vector<byte> m_Seq;
```

//calling in my cpp:

```
vector<byte> writeBytes(m_Seq);
GetLinkCRC16(writeBytes);
```

I have type conversation error when I pass "writeBytes" in to "GetLinkCRC16" method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is "no way" to make the vector with differ type without making a copy (and type conversion).

```cpp
std::vector<byte> writeBytes(m_Seq);

std::vector<uint8_t> writeBytesClone(writeBytes.begin(), writeBytes.end());
GetLinkCRC16(writeBytesClone);
```

What do I mean by saying "no way". There is a way, but it is a [platform-dependent and, probably, UB way to wrap an array in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15203325/6547185).