# Using a Struct with SIMD Intrinsics

Tags: c++, openmp, vectorization, simd

Let's say I have a struct

```
typdef struct point{
 
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;

} point;
```

I have an array of these structs and I want to do the following -

```
std::vector<point> copyArray;

for(auto p : array_of_points){
   
    point newPoint;

    newPoint.x = p.x;
    newPoint.y = p.y;
    newPoint.z = p.z;

    copyArray.push_back(newPoint);
}
```

Now this particular section in my code can be accelerated using vector operations, if I can operate on multiple structs at once.

I have a two part question

- How can this be done using SIMD intrinsic. I am not sure how I would load structs.
- Can OpenMP achieve the desired vectorization. I am not that comfortable with assembly and was not able to figure out whether it was indeed being vectorized efficiently or not.

Comment: If all you want to do is copy the vector then just do `std::vector<point> copyArray(array_of_points.begin(), array_of_points.end())`, the compiler is likely to optimise this to a SIMD intrinsic for you

Comment: you could use sse or avx to load and store vectors

Comment: SIMD generally works better when you have 3 separate arrays, one each for x, y, and z.  You *can* do stuff with a geometry vector inside a single SIMD vector, but it's clunky and slower (for stuff other than copying) than processing 4 xyz geometry vectors at a time, even if you pad your SIMD vectors with xyzw with unused w.    See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info, especially [Slides + text: SIMD at Insomniac Games (GDC 2015)](https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/slides-simd-at-insomniac-games-gdc-2015/) which specifically covers this SIMD anti-pattern.

Comment: e.g. [this code optimises](https://godbolt.org/z/7raY43Wcx) down to a `memcpy` which will use intrinsics internally

Comment: for SIMD you should use [SoA instead of AoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AoS_and_SoA). See [Structure of Arrays vs Array of Structures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17924705/995714), [Improving Vectorization Efficiency using Intel SIMD Data Layout Template](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/presentation/improving-vectorization-efficiency.pdf)

Comment: What is `array_of_points`? If it was also a `std::vector<point>`, just copy-construct `copyArray` from that. If it was a vector of different structs (different type of `x,y,z`, or additional member variables) the question would be different. You should always provide a [mre]!

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the loop can not be vectorized as `copyArray.push_back(newPoint);` is accessing a shared resource.

If you want to speed this up, you might want to look into how to convert arrays into vectors quickly. You could to start your search [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278347/c-pointer-array-to-vector/15203325).

Comment: `std::vector` isn't thread-safe, so any thread accessing it will assume it's the only thread.  (In C++, it would be data-race undefined-behaviour to have multiple threads doing `.push_back()` on the same `std::vector` at the same time, so compilers can and do assume that doesn't happen.  That's why compilers are able to optimize normal code well.)

Comment: So TL:DR, even if `std::vector<point> copyArray;` were global, not a local inside the same function, that wouldn't stop auto-vectorization.  If the compiler manages to untangle the copy in 3x4 = 12-byte chunks into a simple memcpy, it should vectorize or recognize it as memset.